# Laravel use function in query

Tags: php, laravel

In controller get `data` from `db` like this, I want to pass whole of `$request` to another function in this controller to get `price` it calculating price based of many things from `$request`:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$query = Post::query();

$query
->where('province', '=', $user->province)
->where('city', '=', $user->city);

$customers = $query->get();
$customers['calculator'] = $this->calculator($request); // call function
```

my problem is it return like this:

```
{
  "0": {
    "id": 1,
    "hash": "RqH29tkfm1dwGrXp4ZCV",
  },
  "1": {
    "id": 3,
    "hash": "RqH29tkfm1dwGsXp4ZCV",
  },
  "calculator": {
    "price": 1
  }
}
```

But I need to use that function for each data, and result should be like this:

```
{
  "0": {
    "id": 1,
    "hash": "RqH29tkfm1dwGrXp4ZCV",
    "calculator": {
      "price": 1
    }
  },
  "1": {
    "id": 3,
    "hash": "RqH29tkfm1dwGsXp4ZCV",
    "calculator": {
      "price": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want `calculator` assigned to **each** `Customer`, you need to use a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to set a `calculator` key for each item in the `$customers` collection. So you need to loop over it:

```
foreach ($customers as $customer) {
    $customer->calculator = $this->calculator($request);
}
```

Notice that since the `$customer` is a `Model` you should set the calculator as a property. Internally it will be set to the attributes array.